# AppCompatActivity with android 5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, appcompatactivity

I have a problem with my android studio, when I create a project to develop from Android 4.4,automatically extends MainActivity of AppCompatActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

But now I need to develop an application with Android 5.1. And when you create it, the MainActivity NOT extends from AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "want to create a project from Android 5.1" means and what "does not inherit from AppCompatActivity" means.

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`  // Working with 5.1 this line of code is not produced.

Not manually. no automatically

Comment: There are many Android developer support sites, providing assistance [in many languages](http://www.andglobe.com/). You may have better luck on another site. As it stands, I (and others) do not know what your question or comment means.

Comment: The problem is clear , I recommend better not discuss how to solve problems you do not know .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to get what you mean. But actually if you want te give your app a large support of device versions (and be up to date in terms of code/design), you should always use **extends AppCompatActivity**. The current version of the library *android.support.v7.app* is perfectly compatible with Android M.